# Unidentified RAM

Tags: memory, operating-system

Greetings! A server which is equipped with 512GB RAM(16 slots * 32GB) which OS is Ubuntu 22.04. During boot up, server reserving 16259356K(15GB) RAM showed in dmesg that resulted only 498GB is available for the OS. I was unable to identify where 15GB is allocated. Could you please help me.

```
1.) Dmidecode for RAM.
root@apac2-prd241:~# dmidecode -t memory |grep Size
    Size: 32 GB
    Size: 32 GB
    Size: 32 GB
    Size: 32 GB
    Size: 32 GB
    Size: 32 GB
    Size: 32 GB
    Size: 32 GB
    Size: 32 GB
    Size: 32 GB
    Size: 32 GB
    Size: 32 GB
    Size: 32 GB
    Size: 32 GB
    Size: 32 GB
    Size: 32 GB


2.) dmesg log.
root@apac2-prd241:~# grep Memory /var/log/dmesg
[    3.919928] kernel: Memory: 520513460K/536773076K available (16393K kernel code, 4395K rwdata, 10908K rodata, 3360K init, 18708K bss, 16259356K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
[    8.227673] kernel: x86/mm: Memory block size: 2048MB


3.) System RAM.
root@apac2-prd241:~# free -g
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:             497          39         439          17          18         438
Swap:              0           0           0
```

Comment: Maybe faulty RAM. May you please provide the full dmesg-log up until 4seconds?

Comment: Can not be faulty ram as the number of 32gb units is clearly shown.

Comment: I don't believe that the dmidecode reports bad memory locked out, only raw hardware reported size. A faulty 32G stick with 15G locked out still reports 32G in its DMI.

Comment: Hi All, This is not limited to one server, we observed it all Ubuntu 22.04 severs. In Ubuntu < 22.04 servers, the variation is 13 GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each 4K memory page commands a 64B `struct page` overhead, meaning 8 GB of unavailable memory for 512 GB of RAM. Adding some reserved memory due to `crashkernel`, memory mapped devices (ie: graphics adapter) and similar ends with ~15 GB unavailable on your server.

EDIT: you have 6 GB allocated for `crashkernel` (which does *not* show as visible OS allocated memory via `free`), so 8+6=14 GB reserved just by the OS for its own. `dmesg | grep -i reserved` shows hardware reserved ranges, which you can compare with the output of `cat /proc/iomap` (note: the latter shows all ranges, even if they do not really use any physical memory).

Comment: Thanks for looking. Yes, the server is configured with crashkernel which reserved 6GB. I assumed crashkernel memory allocated from OS mem, 497GB (as of free -g). Correct me if I'm wrong. Can you please let me know how can I find memory mapped devices for which memory is allocated.

```root@apac2-prd241:~# grep crashkernel /var/log/dmesg
[    0.011740] kernel: Reserving 6144MB of memory at 520176MB for crashkernel (System RAM: 524192MB)```

Comment: `crashkernel` reserved memory does not show in `free` output. I've edited my answer.